# Name Server 2 not answering to TCP/ Inconsistent Glue

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver, glue-record

I'm using Pingdom's DNS tools to check up on my DNS.

I'm getting these Errors:

> **Too few IPv4 name servers (1).**
>
> Only one IPv4 name server was found
>   for the zone. You should always have
>   at least two IPv4 name servers for a
>   zone to be able to handle transient
>   connectivity problems.
>
> **Inconsistent glue for name server
>   ns2.domain.com**
>
> The address of a name server differed
>   from the child and the parent. This is
>   a configuration error and should be
>   corrected as soon as possible.
>
> **Name server ns2.domain.com does not
>   answer queries over TCP.**

My domain registrar is set to ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com (example).

EDIT: My Questions

How do I enable TCP on my nameservers?
What is 'Inconsistent Glue'?
I have two Name Servers, but I'm getting the "Too Few IPv4" error, what am I doing wrong here?

(P.S: First Rev of post was bad, sorry, early morning post)..

Edit:

I've seem to fixed the First and Second Error by adding "A Record" ns2.example.com -> Pointing to my secondary IP and editing my resolver file.

**Still getting the error, ns2.example not answering queries over TCP.**
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Too vague. Please provide the domain name so we can check the DNS response and be able to help!

Comment: Not sure what the question here is. Absent any other information my recommendations are to purchase a copy of O'Reilly's `DNS & Bind` (Cricket book) and fix the errors reported by Pingdom.

Comment: If the actual domain was provided the issue could be solved in 10 minutes. Otherwise one must guess with incomplete information given by somebody that doesn't necessarily understand how DNS works.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your secondary nameserver as a slave of your primary.  Enable 53/TCP on your firewall and make sure you are listening on that port by trying to telnet your-dns-ip 53.

Resolver's got nothing to do with this.  This is the "server side" of DNS, resolver is a client configuration issue.

I agree with the comments above, just provide the domain name in question and we'd be able to tell you exactly what is wrong.

You don't mention what OS you are running or what nameserver which also makes giving speicific advice more difficult.  I think the following ought to be required reading before posting a question on serverfault or other question sites:

http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html